# Let $v$ be a valuation of DVR of character 0, If $v(p)＞0$, then for all $q≠p$, $v(q)＝0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, valuation-theory

Let $v$ be a valuation of DVR of character 0. Let $p$ be a prime.

I would like to prove

If $v(p)＞0$, then for all $q≠p$, $v(q)＝0$.

If $v$ is usual $p$-adic order, this is trivial.
But I want to check this in general valuation of DVR.

I may not need assumption valuation of DVR, may be arbitrary valuation of valuation ring.

Comment: I think you need to assume that $q$ and $p$ are non-associate, i.e., we don't have $q = up$ for some unit $u$, rather than just $q \neq p$. Even for the $p$-adic discrete valuation, $v(-p) > 0$. (You don't state this, but presumably you're assuming that $q$ is also prime, otherwise we can simply take $q = p^2$ as a counterexample.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's question is poorly worded but the point is to assume that $ap+qb=1$ for some $a,b,p,q$ in a DVR.

If $v(p)>0$ then $v(q)=0$ because otherwise we'd have $v(1)>0$.

Comment: Valuation ring needs to be DVR? Where did you used property of DVR, not valuation ring?

Comment: Any valuation being $\ge 0$ on $a,b,p,q$, no need to be discrete or real valued.

Comment: Could you tell me why $v(a)$≧0 and $v(b)$≧0?